# Safely laminate strings in J without risking replication

Tags: j

If you laminate (`,:`) strings with more than one character, you get a nice padded array:

```
   x =: 'x'
   y =: 'yolo'
   z =: 'zebra'
   y ,: z
yolo 
zebra
```

If you laminate a single character, the scalar is replicated:

```
   y ,: x
yolo
xxxx
```

You can avoid this by turning the scalar into a vector with `$`:

```
   y ,: 1$ x
yolo
x
```

But that's not so great if you're acting blind:

```
   y ,: 1$ z
yolo
z
```

Is there a simple and straightforward way to laminate the strings x and y without knowing ahead of time whether one of them might be only a single character long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f=: ,: & , works fine when there are only 2 strings, but when there are several strings, ravel doesn't feel like the right thing.

```
   f=: ,: & , 
   'yellow' f 'x'
yellow
x     
   'yellow' f 'x' f 'blue'
yellow  
x   blue
```

For that reason, I prefer to introduce a verb to force both arguments to rank 2. Then you can use append instead of laminate.

```
   d2=: 13 : '(_2{. 1 1,$y)$,y'
   g=: ,&d2

   'yellow' g 'x'
yellow
x     
   'yellow' g 'x' g 'blue'
yellow
x     
blue
```

Comment: If you give `d2` something with three or more dimensions, you lose data, don't you? That said, I suppose `g` is nice when you want an array of strings and you don't want to keep track of whether you're doing the initial laminate or are just appending to an existing array.

Comment: Yes. d2 is for things that look like strings but might be either scalar or vector.

Answer (score 3):

Add an axis with `,`, before laminating:

```
y,:,x
yolo
x   

y,:,z
yolo 
zebra
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work if the first argument is the scalar, such as `x,:,y`. I think that leaves us with `(,y),:(,x)`, right?

Comment: Or, I suppose `,:&,` would be prettier.

Comment: @Dane, yes, add the `,` where you think it will be needed.